# sed for replacing with wildcard

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I mean to replace, in file `mydata.txt`, the line

```
<time="0.*" name="file000.txt"/>
```

with

```
<time="0,*" name="file000.txt"/>
```

The "zero point *something numeric*" should be replaced by "zero comma *the-same-thing*".
And I do not have to replace the dot in the file name.

I could detect with `sed` the difference between those two occurrences with `0\.[0-9]` (it matches the first but not the second), but I do not know how to tell `sed` to keep in the replacement string *the-same-thing* (whatever it matched)

```
sed -e 's/0\.[0-9]/0\,?/g' mydata.txt
```

**What should I use instead of `?` in this expression?**

Comment: You need a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) ex. `sed -e 's/0\.\([0-9]\)/0\,\1/g' mydata.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver - Thanks, it is good to know the "official" names for stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the value in a register and restore it from there as follows:

```
sed -e 's/0\.\([0-9]\)/0\,\1/g' mydata.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it. 
One should:

1. Use an escaped pair of parenthesis `\(...\)` enclosing whatever is to be matched in the searched string.
   Up to 9 matches can be used in an expression.
2. Use `\n` to reuse the matched string in the substituted string. `n` is a number between `1` and `9`, corresponding to the number above.

This is

```
sed -e 's/0\.\([0-9]\)/0\,\1/g' mydata.txt
```